# Show more / Show less button - fixing how new content placement work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm implementing a 'view all' button to hide some content in the default state, but expose it when the 'view all' button is clicked on. It's working well except that since the hidden content is an actually very long list (Note: for convenience, I replaced the actual content with "Hidden content goes here, it's a long list....." in the code below), so current setup makes things confusing to users -- right now, when the button is clicked, the (long) hidden list shows above the button and the button STAYS IN THE SAME SPOT.

I'd like to make things more user friendly so that when the button is clicked, I'd like the hidden content to still show up above the button, but would like the button to move to the end (i.e. people would scroll down to access this view less button). And when the view less button is clicked on, the content disappears, and the user is taken to the original place.

This site https://greylock.com/portfolio/ has "view all" button under "featured", and that's exactly how i'd like this button to behave.

[image]

```
<div>content goes here</div>

<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
  Hidden content goes here, it's a long list..... 
</div>

<button id="click" onclick="myFunction()">View All</button>


<style> 
#myDIV {
  display:none;
}
</style>

<script> 
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    $("#click").text("View Less");
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    $("#click").text("View All");
  }
}
</script>
```

Update:

```
  <div> 
    orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="myDIV">
        orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    
    </div>
    
    <button id="click" onclick="myFunction()">View All</button>

<div> 
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 2in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myDIV').slideUp(); // SLIDE DIV UP INITIAL THEN TOGGLE AFTERWARD
           $("#click").click(function () {
               $('#myDIV').slideToggle(1000);
           });
      })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the issue is with the style of the toggle button. Check it does not have a CSS rule forcing to stay on place. Something like `position: fixed`. The same for the list. If it have a CSS rule forcing to stay on place and over the button (position and/or z-index properties), the button will not move.

As a test, remove CSS files and try your toggle script.

What you want to achieve is the normal flow of boxes on HTML. I'm sure there is some CSS making the effect you describe.

Comment: You're right. I tried the code on a brand new file, and the issue was gone. Must be something that I wrote for other parts of the website, but I'm not sure what's causing the issue though - I don't have any "position: fixed" or z-index properties.  What else should I be looking for?

Comment: There have to be some of this on the list or in the button. Is there a lot of CSS? Can you share? Is this project online?

Comment: Hi actually - I don't think the issue is gone. Here's how it's behaving now: https://imgur.com/a/RFdHSis -  It's behaving different from the view all button here. https://greylock.com/portfolio/  I've just shared the code in the 'update' section in the original post. Can I make it behave like the button on the other site? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much easier just by using slideToggle()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myDIV').slideUp(); // SLIDE DIV UP INITIAL THEN TOGGLE AFTERWARD
       $("#click").click(function () {
           $('#myDIV').slideToggle(1000);
       });
  })
```

or you can use the animate function.

```
$('#myDIV').animate({'height' : '300px'}, 1000); // or use %
```

then your css will look like

```
#myDIV{height:0px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Less code, easier to manage. You can also toggle the text as per your example with toggle